# Matlab plot fails when too many values are the same

Tags: matlab, plot

I use Matlabs plot function to create a comparison of two matrices (each 1300x1 double). The values are plotted in hundreds, because every hundred needs its own color and marker type.
It looks like this:

```
Start=1
for i=1:1:13
    plot(ArrayA(Start:Start+99,1),ArrayB(Start:Start+99,1));
    Start=Start+100;
end
```

I left out the parameters for marker and color for readibility.

It usually works fine, but sometimes, there is a special case where ALL the values in the matrices are equal to a certain scalar value (or at least some 1000 or so are and the rest 300 are equal to some other scalar). In these cases, we can be sure that values in ArrayA are equal to values in ArrayB element-by-element.

When this happens, whole matlab fails and gives me "Matlab System Error". If you need details of this error, I am happy to provide it.

I am pretty sure this is linked to the points being equal and hence failing to plot correctly, as in other cases, it works just fine.

I would like to ask you for a suggestion for a workaround, as the solutions does not need to be very neat (as this happens very rarely).

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Did you try to contact MathWorks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
pause(.1)
```

in the loop

OR, you can try defining 1 plot and setting the data everytime:

```
fig = figure;
hold on;
myplot = plot(NaN,NaN,'-')
for i = 1:100
   set(myplot,'XData',X(i),'YData',Y(i))
   dummy = dummy+1;
   drawnow;
end
```

where X and Y are your respective data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the "pause(.1)" thing works ! And just out of curiosity, could you maybe suggest what actually happened ? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: I think it's not getting a chance to clear the old data, so it's trying to handle all the plots at once.  My hypothesis is that you give the graphics card time to catchup with the processor but I really don't know machine ops, so just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange. 1300 of double is nothing and Matlab should be able to handle that. 
I just tried plotting 13000 of the same values on a figure and Matlab did not bother.

Anyhow, I am not 100% sure why Matlab crashes (maybe the full error message could be useful), but if you could be more specific about your problem you are trying to solve, we could maybe find a different solution.

Are you trying to spot the locations in your vectors where you find different values?

Comment: Hi Mohamad, thanks for the answer.

Yes, that is what I am doing. I am plotting y=x straight line and then values of ArrayA against ArrayB to spot trends or big discrepancies between them (different colours of 100s of points indicate special sets of points with specific characteristics, hence allowing for pattern analysis).

However, the look of the plot is mostly set in stone, so we can rule out different types of charts/tables.

The error I get is "Segmentation violation". Do you maybe know what that could mean? Also, is there a part of the error report that is particularly useful?

Ondrej

Comment: Ondrej, segmentation violation is definitely a memory allocation or out-of-range-access issue. Have you tried it this with smaller vector sizes see if you get the same problem?

Comment: Also, a couple of suggestions: have you tried your code on a different machine or matlab version? And regarding your problem, have you thought about plotting only the points which have a non-zero difference, i.e. Diff = ArrayA - ArrayB, and then plot only nonzero values of Diff. Hope you can figure it out soon.

Comment: MomoPP, thanks for your answer, I actually was able to solve it using a second answer from Xurtio. And to answer your queries, smaller vectors did work okay and plotting only the points with non-zero difference is unfortunately not an option. The problem occured on all matlab machines I have at my disposal (three of them all with Matlab R2010b) Thanks anyway !

Comment: No problem. Glad you could fix it. But now, just out of curiosity, I was wondering what the exact problem was and how you fixed it, if you don't mind sharing. :-)

Comment: Certainly not :) However, it is as of now not clear to me. @Xurtio suggested to use pause(.1) in the loop and that worked. I don't actually know how... But, what I noticed as another strange thing is that when debugging and going step by step, the plot worked fine. It was only after running it as a part of a bigger script that it failed (possibly a reason why the pause(.1) thing worked. Well, Matlab continues to amaze me...

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue on `Matlab2010b` on Mac OS X: plotting in a loop, vector would sometimes become all `NaNs`, Matlab would crash then or shortly after but not always.

Reading this thread now, I think it is very probably a race condition between different threads, so the guys from Mathworks should really fix that.

Putting a `pause(0.1)` increases the probability that the other thread can finish first (it is not really a solution, though).

Race condition would also explain why it only happens once in a while, because it depends on the (random) allocation of tasks to threads etc.